# Nginx routing not route to the corresponding route

Tags: flutter, nginx

I'm attempting to route incoming requests by the route names 'client' and 'agent'. However, regardless of the route, it always redirects to the root route. Initially, it loads the corresponding page, but eventually, it defaults back to the root route. Why is this happening?

```
server {
    root /var/www/html/api.technologies.com;  # Change the root to the common parent directory
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name api.technologies.com;

    location /agent {
        alias /var/www/html/api.technologies.com/agent/client;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /client {
        alias /var/www/html/api.technologies.com/client;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ ^/minified:(\w+)$ {
        alias /var/www/html/api.technologies.com/agent/client;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.technologies.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.technologies.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = api.technologies.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name api.technologies.com;
    listen 80;

    location / {
        return 404; # or any other default behavior
    }
}
```

this is my server block and im using flutter web 3.10 for serving html page